# Save a HTML page in Firefox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to save a HTML page using JavaScript in Firefox.
I've tried the code below, but it only works in IE:

```
function doSaveAs() {
    if (document.execCommand) {
        document.execCommand("SaveAs");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it only works in IE: it is a proprietary method, only available in that browser. If I want to save a web page, I'd rather do it myself.

Comment: @Marcel, while I agree with your comment, there's nothing to suggest that he's *not* calling the function in response to user input. Albeit, I don't understand why he's re-inventing an existing browser feature in JavaScript.

Comment: I also thought *(s)he* is doing exactly that, but some malicious programmer can use this for other purposes.

Comment: @Marcel: in which case I offer my apologies for my presumptions... :)

Answer (score 4):

This only works in IE.

Simply tell the user to hit CTRL+S if he wants to save a page. You could also link to a php script which sends the page with appropriate headers (`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="document.html"`) forcing a download window if all the user should save is the HTML page (i.e. without any images, css, etc.).

Comment: I just reconfigured my browser to quit if I hit Ctrl-S. ;-)